# Can anyone recommend me a good pdf link to learn B-spline with a lot of examples?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, spline

I really hope someone can recommend me a good link to study B-spline with a lot of examples that I could grasp the concept very easily! Thanks! :)

Comment: What is B_spline?

Answer (score 2):

[An Introduction to B-Spline Curves](http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~455/bs.pdf) comes up in Google search. For more references you can check [this search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=b%20spline&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=com.yahoo%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox#hl=en&client=firefox&hs=zN9&rls=com.yahoo%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=b%20spline%20examples%20pdf&oq=b%20spline%20examples%20pdf&gs_l=serp.3..33i29i30.6095.10410.1.10581.21.21.0.0.0.2.421.3851.0j16j2j2j1.21.0.ernk_rqr..0.0...1.1.9.psy-ab.7YI43wXowlQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.cGE&fp=f4721b4ee6596e5d&biw=1173&bih=761).